# Spark DateDiff returning 0

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark-sql_2.12 version 3.1.1 in my Java application. I need to run the query bellow. However, there isn't show any error. It only returned 0.  There are dates in the table, an example 2014-11-01.

```
SELECT datediff(current_date(),date) AS diff, cod_equipment FROM equipment WHERE status_equipment > 1 group by  date, cod_equipment ;
```

Some suggestion is appreciated.

I'm using the documentation : https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/search.html?q=datediff .

**EDIT 1:**

**The printSchema() :**

```
root
 |-- diff: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- cod_equipment: string (nullable = true)
```

**The current output:**

```
Pushing operators to equipment 
Pushed Filters: 
Post-Scan Filters: (status_equipment #58 > 1)
Output: cod_equipment#22, date#47, status_equipment #58
```

**EDIT 2:**

PS.: The questions asked by Vicent in the comments below help me to find an error in the database records. The evidences below show the correction.

**The show() :** (The cod_equipment type is UUID)

```
    +-------------+--------------------+
    | diff        |   cod_equipment    |
    +-------------+--------------------+
    |         3275|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         4332|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         4716|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         4115|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         4102|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         4034|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         3259|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         4603|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         3324|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         4229|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         4238|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         4193|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         2811|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         3553|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         2946|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         3961|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         3337|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         5075|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         3098|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    |         2755|3fbfbe6d-6920-468...|
    +-------------+--------------------+
    only showing top 20 rows
```

The `select * from equipment` (I have only one cod_equipment in the base and 288 records).

```
             Date       | cod_equipment
------------------------+--------------------------------------
             2014-03-17 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2010-02-02 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-04-06 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2010-04-25 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-08-08 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-09-05 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-06-03 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2008-11-20 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-07-06 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-09-17 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-10-07 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-07-01 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-07-10 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-11-23 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-07-09 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2014-08-07 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2010-02-18 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2014-06-25 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-01-22 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2009-05-22 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-02-23 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2014-02-08 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-03-24 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2010-03-28 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-12-19 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2009-08-28 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2009-09-19 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-12-27 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-10-23 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-03-23 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2008-04-01 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2014-07-10 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-07-12 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-06-17 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2014-01-13 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-04-09 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-12-21 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2009-06-22 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2014-06-07 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2009-08-23 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-04-25 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-07-23 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-03-04 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-03-08 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2010-06-04 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-09-12 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2008-07-24 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2008-10-25 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2014-06-30 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2008-08-12 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2009-01-30 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-06-30 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-04-22 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-02-25 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-12-19 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-12-23 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-07-28 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2009-10-13 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2008-01-08 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2014-03-14 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2009-02-23 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-11-08 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-04-10 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2009-10-19 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-10-19 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-11-03 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-11-02 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2010-07-02 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2010-03-26 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-10-28 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-10-21 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2010-06-20 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-05-14 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-07-15 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-05-10 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2014-03-04 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2010-06-17 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2014-06-22 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-08-24 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2010-10-20 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2010-03-24 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2008-10-15 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2009-06-25 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-11-11 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2009-10-05 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2008-06-09 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2014-01-27 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-01-18 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2008-07-17 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-05-25 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2008-01-04 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2008-03-01 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-07-19 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2009-11-14 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2013-01-29 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2008-07-12 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2010-12-27 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-03-06 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2012-04-16 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
             2011-05-23 | 3fbfbe6d-6920-4689-a009-cbe506000988
```

Comment: What is the schema of your table ? You can get it by applying `printSchema()` to your dataframe. And can you add a sample of your current output ? Thanks !

Comment: Hi Vicent, I edited the question with your answerds.

Comment: where is 0 in the output? does the input set actually contain records satisfying "where" condition?

Comment: Hi Mangusta, the 0 is in the Java object Dataframe output in the eclipse' s debug perspective inspection with the cod_equpment value. The output in my question is the spark's log output.

Comment: Your `date` might not be the date format.

Comment: @LucianaOliveira Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my previous comment, I would like to see the schema of your input dataframe, not your output dataframe. And also a sample of data from your input dataframe. You can get it by applying `show()` to your input dataframe. If you don't have an input dataframe, you can run the command `select * from equipment` to get it. Thanks !

Comment: @VincentDoba, thanks a lot! Your questions help me to find an error in the database. I correct and it's function now. The CQL's script was wrong. I edit my question with the correct result to show you.